# Не парсит больше одной страницы сайта

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Есть следующая структура пагинации на сайте конкурента:

```html
<nav>
<ul class="pager col-xs-12" id="yw0">
 <li class="page selected"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory">1</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=2">2</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=3">3</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=4">4</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=5">5</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=6">6</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=7">7</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=8">8</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=9">9</a></li>
 <li class="page"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=10">10</a></li>
 <li class="next"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=2"></a></li>
 <li class="last"><a href="/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=432"></a></li>
</ul>        
</nav>
```

Нужно спарсить товары со всех страниц. Есть код, который вытаскивает следующую страницу сайта. Код вида:

```html
$next = $doc->find('.pager .selected')->next()->attr('href');
```

Но он не работает, не тащит ссыль на страницу. Как правильно вытащить в переменную $next искомую страницу исходя из пагинации выше?
Буду признателен за ответ. Спасибо заранее.

```html
<?php 
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';


 function parser ($url, $start, $end) {
   $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

  if ($start < $end) {
   foreach ($doc->find('.lst-itm') as $position) {
   $position = pq($position);

   $img = $position->find('img')->attr('src');
   $description = $position->find('a span')->text();
   $price = $position->find('.cost-item')->text();

   echo "<img src='https://t-don.com/$img'>";
   echo $description;
   echo '<br>';
   echo $price;
   echo '<hr>';
  }

  // $next = $doc->find('.pager a')->next()->attr('href');
  $next = $doc->find('.pager .next a')->attr('href');

  if (!empty($next)) {
   $start ++; 
   parser ($next, $start, $end);
  }
  }
}
 $url = 'https://t-don.com/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory';
 $start = 0;
 $end = 3;
 parser ($url, $start, $end);

 phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Comment: `next()` от выбранного `li` - это следующий `li`. В нем естественно нет атрибута `href`. Также через `find` ищите `a`.

Comment: И судя по коду он ищет .pager .selected, а это (в данном примере) первый элемент <li>, правильнее было бы селектить $doc->find('.pager .next a')->attr('href');

Comment: Ищу как раз 'a'. Возможно неправильно записал код.

Comment: @Stalker
Warning: file_get_contents(/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=2): failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser\index.php on line 8
Ссылку на следующую страницу достало, но мне кажется, что неправильно записан путь...

Comment: конечно не правильно, вы ищете /catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=2 относительно своего сайта, вам нужно указать домен конкурента, потом ссылку

Comment: @madfan41k извините, а как это сделать правильней?

Comment: file_get_contents('h ttps://сайт конкурента.com/catalog/zapchasti-k-selhoztehnike/traktory?page=2')

Comment: @madfan41k сюда можно скинуть весь код? 
У меня в file_get_contents переменная $url в которую передается адрес сайта конкурента. По сути тоже самое.

Comment: прикрепите ваш код к вопросу

Comment: @ madfan41k прикрепил

Comment: @madfan41k     вы не смотрели код?